# Servlet 4.0, JAX-RS 2.1, and HTTP/2 Multiplexing

Tags: java, jax-rs, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am reading https://www.mnot.net/blog/2019/10/13/h2_api_multiplexing and wondering what it means for our HTTP API implemented in JAX-RS 2.1; especially this excerpt:

> Your server implementation will also need to be carefully considered to exploit this kind of request pattern

I've read that Java 9 introduced client APIs for HTTP/2, and that Servlet 4.0 introduced support for HTTP/2 server features like Server Push.

What I'm wondering is if the JDK (or below) are automatically handling the initiation of the HTTP/2 connection and/or the multiplexing aspect of the protocol, or is there something I need to do in our server config to ensure HTTP/2 (and especially the multiplexing feature) is properly supported.  Or maybe its server-implementation-specific?